# mobile safari 5 not responding to js events until further acton

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari

So check out http://www.toyota.ca/toyota/en/vehicles/yaris-hatchback/gallery using ios 5/mobile safari 5 or simulator press an image on the scroller at the bottom and a lightbox pops. Try to press the next button, you noticed nothing happens. Now if you zoom in/out or change orientation or scroll the page, the image will change.

The js works because the next/prev will become enabled/disabled as you press them but it does not do the animation part until further action. Why is this? is this common? If you try the same page on ios 4 it will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a `click()` handler, use a `mousedown()` handler.

Mobile devices have a hard time discerning between a `click()` and a `mousedown()`.

The necessary change is line 472 in `common.js`, change

`var o=p(f,c.prev).click(function(){b.prev()}),q=p(f,c.next).click(function(){b.next()});`

to

`var o=p(f,c.prev).mousedown(function(){b.prev()}),q=p(f,c.next).mousedown(function(){b.next()});`

Either that, or, for every such navigation button, on creation, use:

```
 $(selector).bind('mousedown',$(selector).data("events").click[0].handler)
 $(selector).unbind('click',$(selector).data("events").click[0])
```

Where `selector` is the jQuery selector for the particular element.

Or you can just use `$(class).off` to clear the handler once and for all.

Comment: actually I solved this on my own, the modal's container and the mask was positioned fixed, and mobile safari 5 has a hard time with fixed position items so i changed it to absolute and it all works. I thank you for your effort in looking deeply into the issue and I think your answer deserves the check mark.